# Is there any best way to port all eventbus code to coroutine from a lagacy Android project?

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, porting, greenrobot-eventbus

We have a large lagacy Android project.
It's code contains hundreds of greenrobot eventbus source.
We need to port them to kotlin coroutine version now.
What is the best and high efficiency way to port them to kotlin coroutine version?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java to Kotlin converter from the Code section of the menu
And my suggestion to you is to master the pages with less codes
And finally, first of all, think if you need to do all these things?